# R Officer Slide HyperLink

Tags: r, officer

I am having a problem in the R Officer package which used to work but suddenly stopped. I want to link for any slide that has a question_text ph_label to the slide second to last. This was working for a very long time and just now recently stopped working. The text just refuses to hyperlink.

I have

> version
> _
> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
> arch           x86_64
> os             mingw32
> crt            ucrt
> system         x86_64, mingw32
> status
> major          4
> minor          3.2
> year           2023
> month          10
> day            31
> svn rev        85441
> language       R
> version.string R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
> nickname       Eye Holes

Microsoft® PowerPoint® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit

Here is my loop for the hyperlink. The try function is for title slides that do not have the ph_label = "question_text".

```
      for (ql in 1:length(my_pres)){
        my_pres <- on_slide(my_pres, ql)
        try(my_pres <- ph_slidelink(x = my_pres, ph_label = "question_text", slide_index = (length(my_pres)-1)))
      }
```

Here is an example of one slide summary:

```
>         slide_summary(my_pres,43)
  type id      ph_label  offx      offy   cx   cy rotation fld_id fld_type
1 body  2  ChatGPT_Text 0.335 0.5991874 9.33 1.00       NA   <NA>     <NA>
2 body  3                  NA        NA   NA   NA       NA   <NA>     <NA>
3 body  4               0.200 5.0800000 1.44 0.37       NA   <NA>     <NA>
4 body  5               0.220 0.0000000 9.49 0.60       NA   <NA>     <NA>
5 body  6 question_text 0.200 5.4000000 1.66 0.24       NA   <NA>     <NA>
```